# how to check all the children check

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the following structure:

```
<ul class="main">
  <li class="toggle">
   <input type="checkbox"> information
  </li>
  <ul>
<li class="modulo">
   <input type="checkbox"> General
</li>
<ul>
   <li class="example1">
    <input type="checkbox">
   </li>
   <li class="example2">
    <input type="checkbox">
   </li>
</ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I now need to know  how to set all the children checkboxes to "checked" when the main parent checkbox is checked by the user

Im using jQuery, thanks

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: You can't have `ul` as a direct child of `ul`. [The **only** valid child element of `ul` is `li`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element) So step one is: Fix the markup. :-)

Comment: what are your parent and children checkboxes?

Comment: When posting markup, it helps *enormously* if you indent it in a reasonable way, so it's clearer to everyone what's contained by what. You actually have subordinate elements **out**-dented from their parents, which is quite odd.

Answer (score 2):

Your can change markup like following:

```
<ul class="main">
  <li class="toggle">
   <input type="checkbox"> information
    <ul>
     <li class="example1">
      <input type="checkbox">
     </li>
     <li class="example2">
      <input type="checkbox">
     </li>
   </ul>
  </li>   

  <li class="modulo">
   <input type="checkbox"> General
   <ul>
     <li class="example1">
      <input type="checkbox">
     </li>
     <li class="example2">
      <input type="checkbox">
     </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('ul.main > li > :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you correct your markup:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li class="toggle">
        <input type="checkbox"> information
        <ul>
            <li class="modulo">
            <input type="checkbox"> General
            <ul>
                <li class="example1">
                <input type="checkbox">
                </li>
                <li class="example2">
                <input type="checkbox">
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...this should do it:

```
$(".main input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyozut) | [source](http://jsbin.com/eyozut/edit)

Then you'll want to handle the converse case (unchecking the parent if you uncheck an ancestor so all ancestors are no longer checked), but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score -1):

This toggles the checks: http://jsfiddle.net/

I'd suggest you indent your code for more easy reading too.